# Cache disappears after the server restarts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I am testing the behaviour of cache and this are my test snippets:

At first, these lines of codes will be executed:

```
 HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("test", "true",

        // No Dependencies
        null,

        // No absolute expiration (mimic the behavior of forms authentication)
        System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,

        // Timeout 20 minutes after the last access 
                // (to mimic the behavior of forms authentication)
        new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0),

        // Setting to NotRemovable ensures that if the
                // application pool restarts, you don't lose your cache
        System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,

        // No callback needed here
        null);
```

so i have inserted a `key` and a value to my `cache`.

I will stop my server, remove that snippet and replace it with

`ViewBag.test = "asd" + HttpRuntime.Cache["test"];` to check the previous cache, but it's gone already since it's not displaying anything.

Isn't it meant to be there or this is the normal behavior for it?

I did some researching but i am not sure if this is client side caching. I am kinda new to this and clarifications will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache is an in-memory cache that resides in your application's memory on the server, and stopping the server stops the program, clearing all its memory. So no, you can expect to never have cached values persist after a restart.

Comment: ohhhhhhhh alright, i'm just testing if i can access the cache value regardless of what pc/client am i using as long as i know the key. Will that work?

Comment: @CarloBrew: Yes. Try using a different browser, or Chrome's incognito mode to simulate being somebody else.